# How to use sum statements in Zend Framework1

Tags: zend-framework

How to use **aggerate function** in **zend framework**

```
$select = $this->select()->from(dailyusages, new Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(offPeakTotal)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($dbadapter);
$result = $select
    ->from(
        'table_name',
        array(
            'offPeakTotalSum' => 'SUM(offPeakTotal)'
        )
    )
    ->query(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC)
    ->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```